# Combining multiple lists

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, join

I have 5 sets of lists, which I am going to have to run 5 different threads processing these 5 lists. I also want to show progress on them in a datagrid which is going to require one "combined" list for binding.

Not sure where to start on this one. If I use concat then if I remove an item on the sublist, the parent list will not be updated.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    ObservableCollection<TestObject> _combinedList = new ObservableCollection<TestObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<TestObject> CombinedList
    {
        get
        {
            return _combinedList;
        }
        set
        {
            _combinedList = value;
        }
    }


    List<TestObject> _list1 = new List<TestObject>();
    List<TestObject> _list2 = new List<TestObject>();
    List<TestObject> _list3 = new List<TestObject>();
    List<TestObject> _list4 = new List<TestObject>();
    List<TestObject> _list5 = new List<TestObject>();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridCombined.ItemsSource = CombinedList;

    }

    private void cmdCreateLists_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createLists();
    }

    public void createLists()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _list1.Add(new TestObject(i));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _list2.Add(new TestObject(i*3));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _list3.Add(new TestObject(i*5));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _list4.Add(new TestObject(i*7));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _list5.Add(new TestObject(i*9));
        }

    }

    private void cmdMergeLists_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Doesn't work and if i remove item from sublist, CombinedList doesn't update.
        CombinedList = _list1.Concat<TestObject>(_list2);


    }

}

public class TestObject : BindableObject
{
    private int _number;
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public TestObject(int inNum)
    {
        _number = inNum;
        _name = "John";
    }

}
```

Am I going to have to write some sort of custom collection here ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding all items to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.  This will provide you the combined list.

> If I use concat then if I remove an item on the sublist, the parent list will not be updated.

You can subscribe to the [`ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event for the "combined" collection, and then add or remove from the appropriate backing collection as changes occur.

Comment: Items will be added/removed from the sublists which should affect the combined list, not vice versa.

Comment: @Peter Can you make your "sublists" implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`?  If so, the same logic works, but in reverse....

Answer (score 0):

Use AddRange vs. individual calls to Add()

Or, just have one collection accessible by all the threads and add to it from each of them instead of combining 5 separate collections.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a 'annotated' concatenation of it:

```
var combined = list1.Select(i => new {
        Item = i,
        Origin = list1 }).Concat(
  list2.Select(i => new {
        Item = i,
        Origin = list2 }))
 .ToList(); // TODO extend for more lists
```

That way, you can get an items source list:

```
combined[13].Origin.Remove(combined[13]);
// refresh combined list!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx). You can add any item, including others collections, and controls that are bound to it will receive a flattened view of the all items within.